# Consult an image in new window using dynamic path

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm trying to display an image with dynamic path.

in **component.html** I have:

```
<span (click)='showFile()'>Consult</span>
```

in **component.ts** I have:

```
showFile()
{

    var req= new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', 'http://localhost:6227/api/auth/users/' + this.usrId, false);
    req.send(null);
    this.connectedUser= JSON.parse(req.responseText);

    // let path = '../assets/upload/semone.jpg';     // Static way     (1)
       let path = this.connectedUser.pathPic;        // Dynamic way    (2)

    this.http.get(path, {observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob'}).pipe(map(res =>
    {
        return new Blob([res.body], {type: res.headers.get('Content-Type')});
    })).subscribe(hi =>
    {
         const xx = URL.createObjectURL(hi);
         window.open(xx);
    });
}
```

By using the **Static way (1)**, I can show my picture.

But, I got nothing when using the **Dynamic way (2)**, knowing that **path** has the same value as  `../assets/upload/semone.jpg`

I got [that exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlKnc.png)

> ERROR  {…} ​ error: Blob { size: 192, type: "text/html" } ​ headers:
>   Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit:
>   lazyInit()  } ​ message: "Http failure response for
>   http://localhost:4300/assets/upload/semone.jpg:
>   404 Not Found" ​ name: "HttpErrorResponse" ​ ok: false ​ status: 404 ​
>   statusText: "Not Found" ​ url:
>   "http://localhost:4300/assets/upload/semone.jpg"
>   ​ : {…}

If I close the terminal node.js and restart it with the command `ng serve`, I can show the image with dynamic path

Have you please any idea about solving that issue ?. Big thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using assets folder is done for static use, in dynamic case it's not the solution because `ng serve` loads the application in memory, that's why the newest added items , let say image, pdf, ... cannot be loaded in the current compiled application.

the workaround is referencing to the path resulted from rest api , for example `http://localhost:6227/api/auth/files/img1.jpg`

Hope To Help.